# Can't seem to set Combobox.Background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm developing a Turing Machine simulator for a class on theory, and I'm trying to change the background color of the input area based upon whether the machine would accept the language (basically, one color over the other depending on if it's valid input).

Since I want to provide a couple example inputs, it needs to be a ComboBox. Since the professor needs to test his own inputs, it must be editable as well. So, here we are.

I've tried setting the `ComboBox.Background` property both programmatically and using XAML (via the Property editor), and neither work. I have no problem setting `ComboBox.Foreground`, however.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Turing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Turing Machine Emulator" Height="400" Width="600" Loaded="onload" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="600">

    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="drpProblem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="changeproblem"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblDescription" Content="Language Description" Margin="135,7,90,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Grid Margin="10,0,10,35" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="lblLeft" Content="left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblRight" Content="right" Grid.Column="2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontFamily="Consolas"/>
            <Label x:Name="lblCenter" Content="cur" Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Background="#FFC5FFA4" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="16"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnIterate" Content="Iterate" Margin="10,0,0,64" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="btnIterate_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="236"/>
<!-- This one right here -->
        <ComboBox x:Name="txtInput" Height="23" Margin="10,0,10,89" Text="Input String" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Consolas" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="cboGetInput" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" Background="#FF874343" IsEditable="True" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtMs" Height="20" Margin="251,0,172,64" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="wait (seconds)" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnAutoRun" Content="AutoRun" Margin="0,0,10,64" Click="btnAutoRun_Click" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="157"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTM" Margin="10,38,10,142" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Language" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="14"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnLoadLang"  Content="Load" Margin="10,0,10,117" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="changeproblem"/>
        <StatusBar Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBlock x:Name="stTXTName" Text="StateName"/>
            <Separator/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="stTXTDescription" Text="StateDescription"/>
            <Separator/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="stTXTTransition" Text="NextTransition"/>
            <Separator/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="stTXTNext" Text="NextState"/>
        </StatusBar>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is the code I'm using to try to change the colors around:

```
if (TM.AcceptsString(txtInput.Text))
{
    txtInput.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
    txtInput.Foreground = Brushes.LightGreen;
}
else
{
     txtInput.Background = Brushes.Pink;
     txtInput.Foreground = Brushes.Pink;
}
```

The foreground changes as expected, but the background color never changes from the default White. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some component control within `ComboBox` that I need to be setting properties for, as I did with `TextBoxBase.TextChanged`?

Comment: I just tried your code in a test project and it works ok for me. Sure you're not setting it back to white or null later in your code?

Comment: Positive. The fact of the matter is, it should *never* be white - since every string is either accepted or rejected.

Comment: Also, the background color isn't even showing up in the Designer winder (from the XAML, it should be very much *not* white)

Comment: You have a style overriding it somewhere else. Application level maybe?

Comment: you want to see the background color of combobox while editing the item ?

Comment: I've added no extra styles :(
And yes, essentially. I've got it working such that the color changes correctly on `TextChanged`, but I just can't access the background color of the actual control.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the line after you set the Background? Also, try Snoop to see if it is inheriting a value from somewhere else...

Comment: Yes, I've put in a breakpoint, and the color doesn't change. Although, I should force it to repaint right after just to be sure. Also, Snoop?

Answer (score 0):

Set the FlatStyle attribute of the ComboBox to FlatStyle.Flat. This resolved a similar issue I experienced when the Win 7 Aero theme is turned on: The backcolor of the ComboBox does not show up in the default FlatStyle setting FlatStyle.Standard.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am abroad now and don't have the means to test this out (although the simulator itself turned out beautifully!). I *promise* I will check it out once I get home in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by auto-generating the template for the ComboBox in Visual Studio 2015 (Right Click ComboBox in Design Window -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy)